# Retrieving files from remote IPython notebook server?

Tags: ipython, jupyter-notebook, remote-server

If I don't want to give out SSH access to users of my remote IPython notebook server. Is there a way to let users browse non .ipynb files and download them?

Answer (score 42):

You can use `FileLink` and `FileLinks` that are built-in:

```
from IPython.display import FileLink, FileLinks
FileLinks('.') #lists all downloadable files on server
```

The code above generates:

```
./
some_python_file.py
some_xml_file.xml
some_ipynb_file.ipynb
```

The three items above are links that you can click to download.

[Click here for an example from ipython.org](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/ipython/ipython/blob/1.x/examples/notebooks/Part%205%20-%20Rich%20Display%20System.ipynb#Links-to-local-files)

Comment: How to download all of them with their original folder hierarchy without clicking into every single item?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately due to edge case [reasons](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/8053#issuecomment-80576172), `FileLink` doesn't work for files outside the Jupyter directory.
You can however get around this by creating a link to the file first:

```
os.symlink( file_name, "tmp.txt" )
display( FileLink( "tmp.txt" ) )
```

In reality the workaround above leaves the link on disk. It also assumes everything has a "txt" extension. We probably want to clean up previous links to avoid cluttering the directory, and not rename the downloaded file. Here is a solution that persists only one link at at time and retains the base name:

```
def download_file( file_name : str ) -> None:
    import os
    from IPython.display import display, FileLink
    
    base_name : str = os.path.basename( file_name )
    k_info_file : str = ".download_file_info.txt"
    
    # Remove previous link
    if os.path.isfile( k_info_file ):
        with open( k_info_file, "r" ) as fin:
            previous_file = fin.read()
        
        if os.path.isfile( previous_file ):
            print( "Removing previous file link." )
            os.remove( previous_file )
    
    # Remember current link
    with open( k_info_file, "w" ) as fout:
        fout.write( base_name )
    
    # Create the link
    assert not os.path.isfile( base_name ), "Name in use."
    os.symlink( file_name, base_name )
    
    # Return the link
    display( FileLink( base_name ) )
```