# Trigger File Download within iPython Notebook

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter-notebook

Given an iPython notebook running on an external server, is there a way to trigger a file download?

I would like to either be able to have the notebook be able to initiate the download of a file living on the the external server to the where the notebook is being rendered locally, or perform a direct string dump from the notebook workspace into a text file, downloaded locally.

I.E. a powerful and tool would be a Notebook that can query from a database, alter data, and download the query results as a CSV file.

[image: Notebook]

A quick experiment showed that a cell containing the following renders a link which downloads a file. I'm hoping for a cleaner solution than rendering data into an html frame.

```
%%html
<a href="data:application/octet-stream,'string of things'">Download a file</a>
```

Comment: You can render a hyperlink with Ipython.display.FileLink.
I am sure with some javascript in a markdown cell you can reload the page.

Comment: I saw that, but was unable to render or download the content in the file, found by following the link

Comment: You could display some JS calling `window.open(url)`

Comment: Your idea could be very cool and productivity enhancing.  I'd love to see a widget for `ls` that shows the file list, but each file is a hyperlink which when clicked would trigger a download by the web browser.  That'd be much faster than switching over to a terminal and doing an `scp`.

Comment: actually, here's a pretty functional solution mentioned in [another StackOverflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24439480/415616)

Comment: Any solution using `ipywidgets.Button`? I would like to handle download file I created using `tempfile`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Retrieving files from remote IPython notebook server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24437661/retrieving-files-from-remote-ipython-notebook-server)

Answer (score 16):

I got a working answer from the comments. `FileLink` did the job, which was to be able to download a file from a notebook.

```
from IPython.display import display, FileLink

local_file = FileLink('./demo.xlsx', result_html_prefix="Click here to download: ")
display(local_file)
```

[image]

For the sake of completeness, here is a similar example with `FileLinks`:

```
from IPython.display import display, FileLinks

local_file = FileLinks('./data/', result_html_prefix="Click here to download: ")
display(local_file)
```

[image]

It's not very pretty, so would love some advice for styling it..

Comment: What external server does it work on? On Google Colab, the links go to incorrect localhost:8080/filename (instead of Google Colab address/filename). Perhaps there is an extra argument one can pass to FileLinks?

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, if the file's aren't too large and hence suitable for base64 encoding. This only works in 'recent browsers', but ipynb users will likely have one. This example works with JSON data.

```
from IPython.display import display, HTML
import json
import base64

encoded = base64.b64encode(json.dumps(data).encode('utf-8')).decode('utf-8')
HTML(f'<a href="data:application/json;base64,{encoded}" download="download.json">download</a>')
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a short implementation in the hublib library

https://github.com/hubzero/hublib/blob/master/hublib/ui/download.py

They have several documented examples. (The `cb` argument is used if you want to customize a callback function.)

https://github.com/hubzero/hublib/blob/master/examples/download.ipynb

Answer (score -5):

You can use the `urllib` library to download files or request URLs.

```
testfile = urllib.URLopener()
testfile.retrieve("http://exmaple.com/file.txt", "file.txt")
```