# File download in Voila from Jupyter Notebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook, ipython, jupyter, voila

There are many questions with great answers about downloading a file from a Jupyter Notebook. [Here's one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26497912/trigger-file-download-within-ipython-notebook/60012879#60012879) I added to earlier. That works, but I am unable to click and download that file for a server started with Voila.

Originally I realized I could not download the basic case when clicked through Voila.

```
from IPython.display import display, FileLink

local_file = FileLink('./demo.xlsx', result_html_prefix="Click here to download: ")
display(local_file)
```

[image: output screenshot]

That is from my notebook. I am able to click on the link and download the file. When I start my notebook with Voila it looks more like this..
[image]

**Clicking the link give a 404** ☝️ for a voila server started with

```sh
voila mynotebook.ipynb
```

Since the file clearly isn't being served... I found [this link here](https://voila.readthedocs.io/en/stable/customize.html#serving-static-files) and tried:

```sh
voila mynotebook.ipynb --VoilaConfiguration.file_whitelist="['demo.xlsx']"
```

which unfortunately didn't work.

I saw static content can be served in voila.. I'll keep playing down this road. Has anyone done this before?

Comment: I see, there are lot of troubles going from jupyter to voila.... It looks so promising, but this is a second thing that is a showstopper for me today

Comment: Well, I wouldn't call it a show stopper. By hosting the file as static content and using an anchor tag I could successfully download the file, and style the link however I want for a deployed environment. Not bad, though not clean.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was able to make it work by hosting my file to download as static content as I was trying before. All of this is for a Mac, but it'll be similar for other platforms.

I had to define a custom template in order to get files at `static_root` so they could be served. Relevant [documentation is here](https://voila.readthedocs.io/en/stable/customize.html#an-example-custom-template) for setting up a custom template.

It isn't difficult.. you essentially create a directory where it's expected, copy over some of the default files, then add/change what you will. terminal record might look something like this:

```
cd ~/Library/Jupyter/voila/templates/
mkdir foobar
export DEFAULT_TEMPLATE_PATH=~/anaconda3/envs/voilatest/share/jupyter/voila/templates/default
export TEMPLATE_PATH=~/Library/Jupyter/voila/templates/foobar
cp -r $DEFAULT_TEMPLATE_PATH/nbconvert_templates $TEMPLATE_PATH
cp -r $DEFAULT_TEMPLATE_PATH/templates $TEMPLATE_PATH
```

to which the tree will look like this in my new custom template:

```sh
 {~/Library/Jupyter/voila/templates/foobar}$  tree .
.
├── nbconvert_templates
│   ├── base.tpl
│   ├── lab.tpl
│   └── voila.tpl
├── static
│   └── demo.xlsx
└── templates
    ├── 404.html
    ├── browser-open.html
    ├── error.html
    ├── page.html
    └── tree.html

3 directories, 9 files
```

notice the `static` directory with `demo.xlsx`. I added that in. That is the file I wanted to download via the link.

Starting voila like this...

```
voila mynotebook.ipynb --template=foobar
```

---

Now.. in **mynotebook.ipynb**

*Use an HTML Anchor tag to do the download*. At least `FileLink` fails for me with the following error.

> Path (/voila/static/demo.xlsx) doesn't exist. It may still be in the process of being generated, or you may have the incorrect path.

which isn't much of a surprise since the actual path the file is stored at **isn't** that. It just happens to be the static content uri.

```html
%%html
<a href="./voila/static/demo.xlsx" download="demo.xlsx">Download Excel Sheet</a>
```

Using an anchor will make it hardcoded and I didn't have any issues. I'll also be able to style the anchor more anyways. One catch..  This doesn't work in a regular notebook anymore since it's a URI to a served resource under voila.

Comment: Putting in static let my code see the file too. Something the question states the answer didn't reiterate is that you need to white-list the file when you run voila. `--VoilaConfiguration.file_whitelist="['demo.xlsx']"`